# Problema com Rotas Customizadas e HttpHandler no ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rotas

Num projeto em que estou trabalhando, escrevi um `HttpHandler` para trazer como resposta uma imagem ao invés duma *View*, mais ou menos assim:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
using MeuProjeto.Data;
using MeuProjeto.Infrastructure;

namespace MeuProjeto.HttpHandlers
{
    public class ImagemFuncionarioHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public RequestContext RequestContext { get; set; }

        public ImagemFuncionarioHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            RequestContext = requestContext;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var currentResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response;

            currentResponse.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            currentResponse.Buffer = true;

            var usuarioId = Convert.ToInt32(RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("id"));

            try
            {
                var funcionario = new Funcionarios(GeneralSettings.DataBaseConnection).SelecionarPorId(usuarioId);

                currentResponse.BinaryWrite(funcionario.ThumbnailFuncionario);
                currentResponse.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                context.Response.Write(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Para funcionar com uma rota, esse `HttpHandler` precisa de um `RouteHandler`:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
using MeuProjeto.HttpHandlers;

namespace MeuProjeto.RouteHandlers
{
    public class ImagemFuncionarioRouteHandler : IRouteHandler 
    {
        public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            return new ImagemFuncionarioHttpHandler(requestContext);
        }
    }
}
```

E a configuração da rota fica assim:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using MeuProjeto.Helpers;
using MeuProjeto.RouteHandlers;

namespace MeuProjeto
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.Add(new Route("Funcionarios/Thumbnail/{id}", new ImagemFuncionarioRouteHandler()));

            routes.MapRouteWithName(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

O código acima funciona perfeitamente se eu entrar no seguinte endereço:

> http://meudominio.com.br/Funcionarios/Thumbnail/1

Só que toda vez que eu uso a rota em qualquer tela que seja, os `actions` dos `forms` estragam, redirecionando a requisição POST para este endereço `http://meudominio.com.br/Funcionarios/Thumbnail/1?action=Index&controller=Vagas`.

O que devo fazer?

Comment: Desculpe Cigano, mas não entendi direito. Você chama através do link "http://meudominio.com.br/Funcionarios/Thumbnail/1" e redireciona a POST para o mesmo link?

Comment: Não. Esse link me devolve uma imagem que está no banco de dados, e apenas isso. O `<form>` aponta corretamente para `/Vagas/Edit/123`, por exemplo, mas no `POST` o resultado misteriosamente vai parar no `Thumbnail`.

Comment: Cigano, se estiver usando Asp.net MVC 5, tente isso para ver se resolve... http://goo.gl/bl1W0w

Comment: Já consegui. Acho que ainda hoje posto a resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz a mesma pergunta no SO gringo e me falaram por comentário que a abordagem deveria ser mudada. Não é preciso `HttpHandlers`, modificar rotas ou qualquer coisa do tipo. Simplesmente fazendo o `Controller` devolver um `FileResult` já resolve o problema:

```
public FileResult Thumbnail(int id)
{
    var funcionario = new Funcionarios(GeneralSettings.DataBaseConnection).SelecionarPorId(id);
    return File(funcionario.ThumbnailFuncionario, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
}
```